# Grid action not work

Tags: module, grid, backend

I have a custom module (backend) displaying some data rows with Magento grid, it successfully displays the data, but when i enter some text in filtering textfile and the pass enter, there is an error message

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in 

    C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\app\code\local\namespace\AdminLog\controllers\Adminhtml\AdminLogController.php on line 37
```

here is the relevant setting

```
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminLog/adminhtml_adminlog_grid')->toHtml()
    );
}
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `config.xml` and of the grid class?

Comment: omg i fixed. adminLog -> adminlog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $this->getLayout()->createBlock('**adminLog**/adminhtml_adminlog_grid')->toHtml()
```

just convert to adminlog